# Google blocks 100000..100000

Tags: google

It's a simple question, if you search this string exactly 100000..100000 on Google, you get blocked. That doesn't happen with other search engines which makes me wonder if anybody knows why this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: How entertaining. A quick test by me showed that it is blocked when both numbers are greater-than 99999, even if they're not the same number. The same is not seen for one or three `.`.

Comment: For some time Google have blocked certain queries used by malicious software. Some worms spread by using Google to find vulnerable web sites. Sounds like you stumbled upon such a query.

Comment: On the blocked page itself you can read the reason. Its states: `This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.

This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible.`

Comment: `Sometimes you may see this page if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly. ` One of the line in google's term of service states: `Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.` Looks like the search string has to do with some malicious activity.

Comment: This is worth a read too. http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24947/18379